# REST Controller responds with transfer closed in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement my first REST style controller in Spring MVC.

The problem I'm having is that the connection is always reporting "Transfer Closed". I tried to get the first controller method working but it had the problem, so I tried with a simple hello world example and it still doesn't work.

In Chrome it does return the object JSON, I can see it in the source view, but the connection doesn't send back a 200 status.

Server is Tomcat just base installation.

What am I doing wrong here?

This is the curl command I copied from the Chrome developer tools to a simple hello world controller.

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/admin/regions/json/hello' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Cookie: sidebar_closed=0; ORA_EID_COOKIE_SUPPORT3_0=true; ORA_EID_COMPANY_ID3_0=10083; ORA_EID_ID3_0=7b4145537d746876476c492f524b4468334e526a556b435937694b482b51414a44615266724e6172573954506b7a43343d; ORA_EID_PASSWORD3_0=7b4145537d754b4856324b5345784d5779674e646271697476345a356330645650667967767a325262354450704850303d; ORA_EID_LOGIN3_0=61646d696e406f7261636c652e636f6d; ORA_EID_SCREEN_NAME3_0=7b4145537d7a4f30495a7836517057663136306e714a4a7363436b436242315835306938664f6279385072514d5476633d; ORA_EID_LFR_SESSION_STATE_10114=expired; JSESSIONID=9F89DCBCCFC0762CFA49FF2CAD4656CC' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

And the controller definition:

```
import com.ideafactory.mvc.general.search.SimpleSearchResults;
import com.ideafactory.mvc.locations.common.services.RegionService;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

/**
 * The AJAX Controller handles the AJAX interface to the Region Administration service
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/regions/json/")
public class RegionAJAXController {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RegionAJAXController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private RegionService regionService;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;


    @RequestMapping(value="/suburb_suggest/{searchTerm}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public SimpleSearchResults suburbSuggest(@PathVariable String searchTerm)
    {
        logger.entry();
        SimpleSearchResults results = regionService.getSuburbSuggestions(searchTerm);
        logger.exit();
        return results;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public Greeting hello()
    {
        return new Greeting();
    }

    private class Greeting {
        private String helloWorld = "Hello World";

        public String getHelloWorld() {
            return helloWorld;
        }

        public void setHelloWorld(String helloWorld) {
            this.helloWorld = helloWorld;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Turn on debug logs on the server and post them here.

Comment: ah ok, of course, I didn't even check out the logs on the server! There is a null pointer exception being thrown from an interceptor I'd written. That explains it, I can probably fix it from here.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I have a similar one

Comment: In my case, There are no errors from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an object in the controller. To convert the object to Json you would need Jackson library in the classpath.